# How to resolve unreachable code after return statement warning?

Tags: jquery

Firefox console shows the following warning with this code :
unreachable code after return statement

How to modify the code to no longer have this warning? Thanks.

```
jQuery.fn.is_fluid = function(){
    return true;
    return(this.hasClass("fluid") || this.css("width")=="100%");
};
```

Comment: It looks like somebody stubbed/short circuited this function - just remove, or comment out, the line after `return true;` You might want to get to the root of who put in the `return true` and why, however.

Answer (score 0):

You've got two return statements in that function. Remove the line

> return true;

so that the second return statement is evaluated and the warning will disappear.